# Stuck with date compare in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$urlYear = '2013';
$currentYear = date('Y');
$systemDate = date('d-m-Y');

 if ( ($systemDate >= '01-06-'.$currentYear) || ($currentYear < $urlYear) ) {
        echo 'Here are your results <br>';
        echo 'System Date '.$systemDate.' '.$currentYear.' '.$urlYear;
    } else {
        echo 'No results for you';
    }
?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
(If the current date as formatted by me is >= '01-06'-year of the current year) 
    OR 
(if the $currentYear < $urlYear)
//echo 'Here are your results';
```

But I seem to be getting true for everything. Can you pls help?

Comment: I'd rather format dates as YYYY-mm-dd so you could compare them as strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare date after converting it to unix timestamp using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php),

```
if ( (strtotime($systemDate) >= strtotime('01-06-'.$currentYear)) || ($currentYear < $urlYear) ) {
   echo 'Here are your results <br>';
   echo 'System Date '.$systemDate.' '.$currentYear.' '.$urlYear;
} else {
   echo 'No results for you';
}
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/X5yWwd)**

Comment: This works. Do I also have to do `strtotime` for even the `$currentYear` and other date variables in my code (see those 3 up there?)?

Comment: It will be good if do. As long as `$currentYear` is concern its ok if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Format your date strings *YYYYmmdd* when you compare, it will act like an incremental **INT**. With that, comparing would be easier.

```
$systemDate = date('Ymd');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create DateTime objects with the dates you have and compare these

```
$UrlYear = new DateTime('2013' . '-01-01'); 
$CurrentYear = new DateTime(date('Y') . '-01-01');
$SystemDate = new DateTime();

if ( ($SystemDate >= $CurrentYear) || ($CurrentYear < $UrlYear) ) {
    echo 'Here are your results <br>';
    echo 'System Date '. $SystemDate->format('d/m/Y') .' '. $CurrentYear->format('Y') .' '. $UrlYear->format('Y');
} else {
echo 'No results for you';
}
```

Comment: Hmm... In your answer `if ( ($SystemDate >= $CurrentYear 'This part should be 01-06-year of the current year' How is that done with the approach you've used? See question) || ($CurrentYear < $UrlYear) )`

Comment: Oh sorry, You can replace the $CurrentYear variable by "$CurrentYear = new DateTime(date('Y') . '-06-01');". This way the currentyear variable is 01-06 of this year.

Answer (score 0):

compare date time using timestamp format, use mktime function to convert your date time to timestamp format

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings lexically. This doesn't work with formatted date strings.

Transform everything to unix timestamps (UTC) and compare numbers or use `date_diff` functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use date for comparison but it should be in Y-m-d format:

```
$systemDate = date( 'Y-m-d' );
$targetDate = date( 'Y-m-d', mktime( 0, 0, 0, 6, 1 ) );

if ( $systemDate >= $targetDate ) {

}
```